..."it is today"... in between of a grammatically complete sentence and not a relative clause
Might anyone help me analyze the following sentence?
What is the grammatical function of "it is today"?
I think it is not a relative clause, right?
But if it is not relative clause, it is beyond my understanding of English grammar ....
The Sentence:
In the decades since she left in 1966, the city has transformed dramatically, but the smells and views of the ultramodern megalopolis it is today continue to fire my senses and feed my imagination.
source: https://cn.nytimes.com/culture/20241115/shanghai-china-books/dual/

It is indeed a relative clause. Insert "that" before.

Compare:  The people who built and lived in that house have passed on but the silver maple they planted in the front yard years ago is a presence in the neighborhood come autumn.
